More on rationally independent subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.
Suppose that $\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}, \lambda_{3}\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and that $\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}, \frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1}\in\mathbb{R}^{+}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ such that the set $\{1, \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}, \frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1}\}$ is rationally independent.
Does anyone have any suggestions to prove the following
$$\overline{\mathbb{R}\left(1,\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}, \frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1}\right)+\mathbb{Z}^{3}}=\mathbb{R}^{3} \hspace{1cm}?$$
I tried using sequences, I have not been able to get the same sequence of integers to satisfy two of the three convergences.
Also, from hypothesis, $\frac{\frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1}}{\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.
Here
$\mathbb{R}^{3}=\{ (x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}) : x_{i}\in\mathbb{R},\hspace{0.1cm}\forall j=1,2,3 \}$.
$\mathbb{R}\left(1,\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}, \frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1}\right)=\{ r\left(1,\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}, \frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1}\right)=\left(r,r\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}, r\frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1}\right) : r\in\mathbb{R}\}$.
A set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is said to be rationally independent if given $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in A$ and $(k_1, \ldots, k_n) \in \mathbb{Z}^{n} \setminus \{(0,\ldots,0)\}$ imply $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} k_i a_i \neq 0$.
Thanks

A couple of clarification questions:  (1) What does the overbar notation signify in the proof statement?  (2) What is the significance of $\lambda_{1}$ in the above?  This might be helpful additional context.  Thank you.

the overbar notation signify that the set $\mathbb{R}(1,\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}, \frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1})+\mathbb{Z}^{3}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

We can write $\omega := (1, \lambda_2/\lambda_1, \lambda_3/\lambda_1) = (1, u, v)$ where $u, v \in \mathbb{R}_+ \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ and $\{1, u, v \}$ is a rationally independent set. The question amounts to prove that the image of
$$\gamma : \mathbb{R} \simeq \mathbb{R}(1, u, v) \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \overset{\small{\mbox{proj}}}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{T}^3 := \mathbb{R}^3 / \mathbb{Z}^3 $$
is dense in the torus $\mathbb{T}^3$. Using coordinates $x := (x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb{T}^3$, this image is the orbit of the dynamical system $dx/dt = \omega$ with initial condition $x(0) = (0,0,0)$.
From this perspective, the result is a special case of the general theorem about the density (in fact, the equidistribution) of the orbits of 'irrational translations' in tori $\mathbb{T}^n$. See e.g. Arnold's Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics, section 51 (subsection B for statements, and C for proofs).
Note that in fact, it is sufficient to prove that $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R} \overset{\gamma}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{T}^n$ is dense/equidistributed (where $\gamma$ is an orbit of an irrational rotation in $\mathbb{T}^n$). The prototypical case here is $n=1$, i.e., iterations of an irrational rotation of the circle. Equidistribution here is often proved via the help of Weyl's criterion. (Arnold uses very closely related ideas, but geared toward proving (implicitly) that irrational rotations are ergodic.)
Back to your special case: since $\omega$ is rationally independent, for all $l = (l_1, l_2, l_3) \in \mathbb{Z}^3 \setminus \{(0,0,0)\}$, we have $l \cdot \omega \neq 0$, and in fact $l \cdot \omega \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. For $j \in \mathbb{N}$, define $v_j = j \omega$. Then the tree-dimension Weyl criterion states that the sequence $\{v_j\}_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ is equidistributed modulo $1$ iff
$$ \mbox{for all $l \in \mathbb{Z}^3\setminus \{(0,0,0)\}$, } \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=0}^n e^{2 \pi i \, l \cdot v_j} = 0 \, .$$
In your case, this criterion is easily verified, since
$$ \left| \sum_{j=0}^n e^{2 \pi i \, l \cdot v_j} \right| = \left|\sum_{j=0}^n (e^{2 \pi i \,  l \cdot \omega})^j \right| = \left|\dfrac{1 - (e^{2 \pi i \,  l \cdot \omega})^{n+1}}{1 - (e^{2 \pi i \,  l \cdot \omega})} \right| \le \dfrac{2}{\left| 1 - (e^{2 \pi i \,  l \cdot \omega})\right|}$$
where $l \cdot \omega$ is irrational (so that $e^{2 \pi i \,  l \cdot \omega} \neq 1$) and the last bound is independent of $n$.

Thanks for the help about the bibliography.

In Tausk is showed the following
Lema 1.
Given $x=(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n})\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ then
$$\mathbb{Z} x+\mathbb{Z}^{n}\hspace{0.1cm}\mbox{is dense in}\hspace{0.1cm}\mathbb{R}^{n} \Longleftrightarrow\{1,x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\}\hspace{0.1cm}\mbox{is rationally independent}.
$$
Lema 2.
Suppose that $\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2} , \lambda_{3}\in\mathbb{C}^{*}$ with $\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}, \frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1}\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$. Then
$$\left\{1,\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}, \frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1}\right\}\hspace{0.1cm}\mbox{is rationally independent if and only if}\hspace{0.1cm}
\mathbb{R}\left(1, \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}, \frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1}\right)+\mathbb{Z}^{3}\hspace{0.1cm}\mbox{is dense in}\hspace{0.1cm}\mathbb{R}^{3}.$$
Proof.
Let $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$ then $\left(y-\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_3}z , y-\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}x\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Note that $\left\{1,\frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_2}, \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}\right\}$ is also rationally independent. By Lemma 1. (for $n=2$), there are sequences of integers $(l_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}, (m_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(k_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that
$$l_{n}\left(\frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_2}, \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}\right)-(m_n , k_n)\hspace{0.1cm}\mbox{converges to}\hspace{0.1cm}\left(\frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_2}y-z , \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}y-x\right)\hspace{0.1cm}\mbox{when}\hspace{0.1cm}n\to +\infty.$$
For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ define $r_{n}:=x-k_{n}\in\mathbb{R}$ then
$$r_{n}\left(1, \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}, \frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1}\right)+(k_n , l_n ,m_n)\hspace{0.1cm}\mbox{converges to}\hspace{0.1cm}\left(x,y,z\right)\hspace{0.1cm}\mbox{when}\hspace{0.1cm}n\to +\infty.$$
Reciprocally, we will show that $\mathbb{Z}\left( \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}, \frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1}\right)+\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Indeed, let $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and consider $(0,x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$, by hypothesis, there are sequences $(r_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $(k_n , l_n , m_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq\mathbb{Z}^{3}$ such that
$$r_{n}\left(1, \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}, \frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1}\right)+(k_n , l_n ,m_n)\hspace{0.1cm}\mbox{converges to}\hspace{0.1cm}\left(0,x,y\right)\hspace{0.1cm}\mbox{when}\hspace{0.1cm}n\to +\infty.$$
Therefore
$-k_{n}\left(\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}, \frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1}\right)+(l_n , m_n)\hspace{0.1cm}\mbox{converges to}\hspace{0.1cm}\left(x,y\right)\hspace{0.1cm}\mbox{when}\hspace{0.1cm}n\to +\infty.$
